# No such column exception in Android SQLite Database while selecting rows

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am working with android SQLite database.
I am getting SQLLite exception as 
'Caused by:`android.database.sqllite.SQLITEException:no such column DD(code 1):`, while compiling :

`SELECT _id, sms, contact, time FROM messages WHERE contact =DD-Aircel ORDER BY _id DESC '`

while selecting rows having contact as DD-Aircel (not while inserting the same).
I think it is due to hyphen '-' in DD-Aircel.
Datatype of column contact is STRING.
Can any1 plz explain with the solution.
Thanks in advance .

Comment: DD-Aricel is a string, thus needs to be surrounded by quotes, always surround strings with quotes!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what you want to do is the following:

```
db.query(DATABASE_MSGTABLE,                                                    // Table name
    new String[] { KEY_MSGGROWID, KEY_MSGSMS, KEY_MSGCONTACT, KEY_MSGTIME },   // Columns to select
    "contact = ?",                                                             // selection (WHERE clause)
    new String[] { "DD-Aircel" },                                              // Arguments for the Where clause
    null,                                                                      // GROUP BY (leave null because you're not grouping)
    null,                                                                      // HAVING (leave null because you're not grouping)
    "_id DESC");                                                               // ORDER BY
```

If you are always filtering by the same contact name (i.e. you're always filtering on the value `"DD-Aircel"`), it is safe to simply use the selection query `contact = 'DD-Aircel'`.

Using the selection query `contact = ?` allows for you to filter by any arbitrary `contact` name. You should do this when the contact name is not known in all cases. This approach ensures that the query works, even if the contact name contains a single quote (e.g. if the contact name is `Dad's Cell`).

Comment: Tx Tim, ur method also works fine even with a column entry having some special characters like single quote. Tx agaim 4 giving thesuggestion

Answer (score 0):

Put the value in quotes:

```
WHERE contact ='DD-Aircel'
```

If you are using query, use parameterized values like:

```
String selection = "contact = ?";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { "DD-Aircel" };
```

Comment: How about showing the right way? Using placeholder `?` and arguments?

Comment: Actually in code, i am not using raw query. What i am doing is

Comment: db.query(DATABASE_MSGTABLE,new String[] {KEY_MSGROWID,KEY_MSGSMS, KEY_MSGCONTACT,KEY_MSGTIME},projection,null,null,null,sortOrder);

Comment: where projection="DD_Aircel and sortOrder=_"idDesc"

Comment: I think you are getting project and selection mixed up

Comment: projection="DD-Aircel"

Comment: projection="DD-Aircel" doesnt really make sense - projection is the columns you want to select. But DD-Aircel is not the name of a column, its a value in the data

Comment: Thanks greg ennis for ur valuable answer, u r correct. Bt projection="contact=DD_Aircel" is also giving the same exception. Is now projection format correct ?

Comment: Thats actually the selection but you need to put quotes around DD_Aircel as in my original answer. And people apparently got upset that I didnt use ? with selectionArgs so you could do it that way also.

Comment: Tx man ! Yeah, acually projection="contact=1234" ie. with some integer was working fine so i ddint notice bt with some string as in my case, DD-Aircel also.need to be suroundd with single quotes.